# TypeError when creating a class

Tags: types, typeerror, python-3.4

Today, some unexpected behavior came up. When I wrote this:

```
class ErrorPost(object):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = "[Error]" + message
        print(self.message)
        del self

class ErrorLog(ErrorPost):
    def __init__(self, message):
        super().__init__(message)
        del self
```

This code throws an error, when creating an ErrorLog object:

```
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

Why is this? I am not manipulating the type of anything, and am not trying to make an object into another type, such as an int. What is happening, here?

I am limited on the amount of code I can post, sorry.

Full Stack Trace:

```
C:\Python33\python.exe C:/Users/******/Documents/MalwareTycoon/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/******/Documents/MalwareTycoon/main.py", line 151, in generate_network
    ********Dict[self.*********] = ***(self.available*****Dict[randint])
IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/******/Documents/MalwareTycoon/main.py", line 201, in <module>
    Game = Game()
Image loaded: C:/Users/******/Documents/MalwareTycoon\images\background.PNG
  File "C:/Users/******/Documents/MalwareTycoon/main.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.computers = self.generate_network()
  File "C:/Users/******/Documents/MalwareTycoon/main.py", line 153, in generate_network
    errorLog= ErrorLog["Apple Computers needed, but no OS available"]
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? Also, why `del self`? It's entirely pointless.

Comment: true.... meh..... I will post as much as I can, give me a sec @user2357112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
errorLog= ErrorLog["Apple Computers needed, but no OS available"]
```

You used brackets. You need parentheses to create an object:

```
errorLog= ErrorLog("Apple Computers needed, but no OS available")
```